# Display error message when blocked words entered in text boxes on button click in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Requirement:

Need to display an error message on button click when blocked words are entered in 3 available text boxes using JavaScript function.
Given:
1) 100 blocked words are already provided, so planning to save it in JSON file or please recommend what approach is good?
2) The onclick function already present. Need to add logic to above requirement
3) Need to use plain JavaScript.

Have done the same thing in Angular JS using $http. But not able to move ahead for plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Put the blocked words into an array, then iterate through each word, checking the inputting word against the blocked list - if there's a match, throw an error.

the click function would be something like:

```
yourArr.forEach((val) => {
  if (enteredWord === val) {
    //throw error
  } else {
    //do whatever you want
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The solution works but need to store the blocked words in external file like JSON,txt, js etc. Not sure how to refer that in my page. Used <script src="~/scripts/Login/blockedwords.json"></script> not working. Can I put all these words in a JavaScript file and then refer?

Comment: Try <script type="text/javascript" src="/blockedwords.json></script> - Make sure your path is correct. It's probably easiest to save that JSON file in the same directory as your javascript file.  Please mark correct if the answer helps you :)

Comment: @ShruthiKrishna please mark the answer correct if the solution worked! Thank you!